# Windows CE - VBScript command to determine free space of drive

Tags: vbscript

Does anyone know if a VBscript command exists to run in Windows CE for determining the size of a drive and free space remaining on a drive?

All the commands like WinMGMTs or fileobject.free space doen't seem to be available in the Windows CE 5.0.

This must be a VBScript so I don't know how the link below will work or could convert. [How can I determine free space on a Windows CE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971404/how-can-i-determine-free-space-on-a-windows-ce-device)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`FreeSpace` property of a [*drive* object from *Scripting Runtime Library*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts2t8ybh(v=vs.84).aspx):

```
Dim fso, ddd
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ddd = fso.GetDrive( fso.GetDriveName("C:"))
WScript.Echo fso.GetDriveName("C:"), FormatNumber( ddd.FreeSpace/1024, 0)
```

or parse last line from `dir /-c` output which could look like

```
   15 Dir(s)     84849643520 bytes free
```

(I will delete my answer if it does not apply to *Windows CE 5.0*)